# Unable to install Qt XUBUTNU 12.04 fresh install

Tags: installation, xubuntu, qt, emacs

I've Qt SDK which is an offline installer. According to the instructions given for installation, first I have to

**chmod u+x Qt_SDK_Offline.run**

then

**./Qt_SDK_Offline.run**

But when I do **./Qt_SDK_Offline.run**, it's saying you don't have permission.

Answer (score 1):

### For problem 1

**Step1**: copy the file to the Desktop or home folder(This is because if the File is on an external drive you have to mount that with execution properties which is not done on Ubuntu by default)

**Step2**: right click on the file and chose properties ,and check the allow the file to execute button.close

[image]

**step3**:Double click on the program

Done!!!